# How to tackle this random number Python homework?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my homework:

> Write a function that repeatedly generates random integers in the range [0,n[, until two consecutively generated numbers are identical.then return the number of generated numbers.

Here is what I did:

```
def function(n):
    for i in range(100):
        random.randint(0,n)
```

and this outputs a hundred numbers, however I need it to stop when it detects two identical numbers, how is that done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @trincot: Yeah I just noticed. Well in that case you simply hold a variable that stores the previously generated one.

Comment: Use two variables, one for the newest random number, and the other for the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use two names: one for the newly generated random number, and one for the previous one.

You need also to make your loop differently, as you don't know how long it needs to iterate before getting a match:

```
import random

def function(n):
    a = -2
    b = -1
    i = 0
    while a != b:
        a, b = random.randint(0,n), a
        i += 1
    return i

# Sample run    
times = function(400)
print (times)
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/6)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

To do it without assigning `a` and `b` strange values, use an infinite `while` loop, then `break` when the values are the same. This is similar to @trincot's solution:

```
import random

def function(n):
    a = None
    i = 0
    while True:
        a, b = random.randint(0,n), a
        i += 1
        if a == b:
            return i

# Sample run    
times = function(400)
print(times)
```